# Function.prototype.bind example

Tags: javascript, bind

```js
function Person(arg) {
 if (this.name == undefined)  this.name = arg ? arg : "tom";
 console.log("Name: " + this.name);
}
Person.prototype.setName = function(value) {
 this.name = value;
};
Person.prototype.getName = function() {
 return this.name;
};
var myobj = {name : "james"};
var new_func = Person.bind(myobj);
new_func();     // Name: james
var obj = new new_func();   // Name: tom
console.log(obj.getName());   // tom
```

Is there anyone who can explain why the last two codes show me "tom" rather than "james"?

In my thought, the new_func is binding the myobj to the Person constructor function, so the obj Object should be a instance of the Person and also it should be bound to myobj. But it appeared whole differently.

Comment: You should probably read the documentation of `new`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new (here: *"The constructor function Foo is called with the specified arguments and this bound to the newly created object."*)

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze the code.

```
var myobj = {name : "james"};
var new_func = Person.bind(myobj);
new_func();                 // Name: james
var obj = new new_func();           // Name: tom
console.log(obj.getName());         // tom
```

First you declare an object literal, where there's a key that you intend to use as a property of your future new *Person*.

Next, you assign `new_func` to a binding of *Person* and *myObj*.
That way, the constructor `Person` is binded to the object literal. However, you are creating a new function with that function body. Sure you'll be able to invoke it, but there will not be any new object created.

If you just want to give a *Person*, a *name*, it's better if you choose to do it via constructor parameters.

```
function Person (name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

And invoke it using new

```
var p1 = new Person("James");
console.log(p1.name);
```

However, if you want to make an existing object *instance* of another, you should use `Object.create([...].prototype)`.

```
var myobj = Object.create(Person.prototype);
var myobj.name = "james";

console.log(myobj instanceof Person);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we check the polyfill for bind

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {

          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
```

in the code we can see apply is called with the object based on the following condition
  `this instanceof fNOP ? this : oThis`, where `oThis` is `myobj` in our case and `fNOP` is created to make the protoype link intact for newly created method through bind. So when we  use new operator new `new_func()` then this will be an istance of fNOP. So the current object will be `this` instead of `myobj`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case when you are using `bind` you are creating a new *bound function* with the same function body of `Person`.

**But** when you are invoking it to create a `new` instance of `Person` you are not passing any parameter so it will create anew element with the default parameter `Tom` for name.

You can read from the bind() documentation that:

> The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the same function body (internal call property in ECMAScript 5 terms) as the function it is being called on (the bound function's target function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(), which cannot be overridden. bind() also accepts leading default arguments to provide to the target function when the bound function is called.

In the following instructions:

**1)**

```
new_func();
```

You are calling the `new_func()` with `myobj` as this reference.

**2)**

```
var obj = new new_func();
```

You create an instance with `obj.name = "Tom"`, the default parameter.

**Solution:**

```
var obj = new new_func(myobj.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

> why the last two codes show me "tom" rather than "james"?

Because `bind` does return a "bound function", which is different when [[call]]ed, but does not change the behaviour of a [[construct]]ion. It is impossible to `bind` constructors, `new` will always create a new instance and ignore the bound value.

You shouldn't be using `bind` on constructors, it's meant for methods. To further clarify what happens, see this example:

```
function Person(arg) {
    console.log("uninitialised", this);
    this.name = arg;
}
var o = {name: "james"};
var bound = Person.bind(o);

var x = new bound("frank"); // uninitialised Person {}
console.log(x); // Person {name: frank}
console.log(o); // Object {name: james}

var x = bound("frank"); // uninitialised Object {name: james}
console.log(x); // undefined
console.log(o); // Object {name: frank}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to bind the function itself, try doing this:

```
obj.getName().bind(myobj);
```

According to Mozilla's examples, you can only call bind on a function [See documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: `Person` is a function